# Unable to access PHP script (IF) after a POST event

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

I'm an obvious newbie. 
I trying to make a contact form with HTML5 and using PHP mail function, however, my form action is calling for contacto.php but after submit, It never enter the IF, it just keep skipping this code. I thought that maybe a bracket was missing or something on my HTML form I even checked that PHP Mail was working and so far everything looks but it just simply won't execute IF. Any ideas? Here's Part of my code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['correo'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];
    $human = $_POST['human'];
    $from = 'From: Demo ';
    $to = 'user_one@webserver.com';
    $asunto = 'New Incoming Message';

    $body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Pregunta: $categoria\n Comentarios: $comentarios";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '8') {                
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Information made it to IF")';
        echo '</script>';
        if (mail($to,$asunto,$body)) { 
            echo '<p>Your Message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>An error occurred. Try again.</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '8') {
        echo '<p>Wrong answer to Anti_spam. Try again!</p>';
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="contacto.php">
    <label for='nombre'>Nombre:</label>
    <input type='text' name='nombre' placeholder='Primer Nombre' required>

    <label for='correo'>Email:</label>
    <input type='email' name='correo' placeholder='Email' required>

    <label for='categoria'>Categoria:</label>
    <input type='text' name='categoria' placeholder='Category'>

    <label for='comentarios'>Comentarios:</label>
    <textarea name='comentarios' placeholder="Additional Observations..."></textarea>

    <label>¿4 + 4?</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="resultado" required>

    <input type='submit' value='Enviar correo' id='btnSubmit'>
</form>
```

Comment: What the value of `POST['submit']` and $human?

Answer (score 1):

Do a :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

at the beginning of your page, that way you will display what is inside your $_POST variable.
Once this is done, you'll maybe figure out what the problem is :)

Post the content of the dump in case you don't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

I know @Alex is trying to get you to deduce it yourself (which is a good thing), but for a beginner you probably won't pick up on what he was getting at.

You are checking to see if the data was submitted by $_POST - which is what you want to do, but the block of code where you are saving your $_POST variables to other variables is not contained in that block - so it is attempting to save them the first time the page is loaded, **not** when it is submitted.